# Highlight all countries a person has visited

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, attribute-table, select-by-attribute, arcgis-10.7

I am interested if it is possible to select a Person in the Attribute table and directly see
which coutries are affected by highlighting them.

Example:
(Here Person 07 is selected and the countries Czech Republic and Estonia should be highlighted in
the Map View.)

[image]

I am working with ArcGIS 10.7.

I assume I have to do it via Python/SQL!?

Comment: Your question seems to be mostly about ArcMap with a brief mention of QGIS. To make it more focused I recommend that you [edit] QGIS out and ask about that in a separate question.

Comment: This is certainly possible, so your question should focus on what you have attempted, and include your code attempt. This would have been easier if your table was normalized into the form `{Person,CountryVisited}` because then it would be a simple subselect (`WHERE country IN (SELECT countryvisited FROM tab WHERE person = 'PERSON01')`) The way this is architected, your code will be less maintainable.

Comment: Listfields, da.Searchcursor and list comprehension with if/else clause to generate the sql statement